# Avoid unique constraints while inserting into table using oracle

Tags: oracle

i am using this query

```
insert into file_status(file_status_sid, client_request_id,date, file_name)
select status_pk_seq.nextinterval, c.client_request_id, sysdate, c.file_name from coverage c;
```

i always run into

```
unique constraint client_request_id_unique violated
```

any ideas how to ignore that ? as coverage table has duplicates client_request_ids

Thanks

Comment: Constraints are defined for a reason - to prevent bad data. either clean up the source table, or try adding "distinct" clause.

Comment: You need to decide which duplicates you exclude from insert. Once you describe your decision here, we could give you exact sql solution.